# Spring @Transactional doesn't apply transactional behavior to method

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

I try to get my hands dirty with Spring + JPA and I read Spring in Action 4th edition. Because of code samples there are incomplete I look for needed parts of code myself in web. But seems I did smth wrong because when I call EntityManager.persist() it doesn't work. No even exception thrown

My code below

**DataConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        SingleConnectionDataSource ds = new SingleConnectionDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname");
        ds.setSuppressClose(true);
        ds.setUsername("user");
        ds.setPassword("password");
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfb.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        emfb.setPackagesToScan("spittr.domain");
        return emfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource ds){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(ds);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public class JpaSpittleRepository implements SpittleRepository{

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    //other methods...

    @Transactional
    public void save(Spittle spittle) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.persist(spittle);
    }

}
```

So in this configuration save() saves nothing.

Of course if explicitly add a pair of lines of code to that method like:

```
@Transactional //unnecessary now
    public void save(Spittle spittle) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(spittle);
        tx.commit();
    }
```

save() works fine (even without @Transactional)

Also I found that @Transactional **does** wrap save() method with doBegin() and doCommit() methods of JpaTransactionManager.

Where would you suggest to dig more to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That same book offers another way of configuring Repository by replacing injection of EntityManagerFactory with EntityManager:

```
    //@PersistenceUnit
    @PersistenceContext
    //private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;
```

As explained, calling emf.createEntityManager() in each method creates new EntityManager which complicates matters concerning transactions

Now it works, though for me the root cause of problem still unclear